# CFRunLoopSourceSignal doesn't work

Tags: macos, qt, events

I'm debugging Qt5.3.1 on Mac, because my program freezes sometimes (intermittent ). I discovered that it is because the QTimer can't work properly.

In Qt code, they use the following two lines to trigger function activateTimersSourceCallback

```
CFRunLoopSourceSignal(d->activateTimersSourceRef);
CFRunLoopWakeUp(mainRunLoop());

void QCocoaEventDispatcherPrivate::activateTimersSourceCallback(void *info)
{
    static int counter = 0;
    NSLog(@"finished activeteTimersSourceCallback %d", counter++);
}
```

but sometimes, these two lines doesn't work, activateTimersSourceCallback won't get called.

I googled, but I couldn't find any solution? is this a known OS bug?

the initialization details:

```
// keep our sources running when modal loops are running
CFRunLoopAddCommonMode(mainRunLoop(), (CFStringRef) NSModalPanelRunLoopMode);

CFRunLoopSourceContext context;
bzero(&context, sizeof(CFRunLoopSourceContext));
context.info = d;
context.equal = runLoopSourceEqualCallback;

// source used to activate timers
context.perform = QCocoaEventDispatcherPrivate::activateTimersSourceCallback;
d->activateTimersSourceRef = CFRunLoopSourceCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0, &context);
Q_ASSERT(d->activateTimersSourceRef);
CFRunLoopAddSource(mainRunLoop(), d->activateTimersSourceRef, kCFRunLoopCommonModes);
```

Comment: Was the run loop source scheduled on the "main" run loop? In what modes? In what mode is the main run loop running at the time that the source is signaled and the run loop woken up? Is it certain that `mainRunLoop()` is always returning the same run loop every time? (Is there a reason why it's not just `CFRunLoopGetMain()`?)

Comment: added initialization details

Comment: That answers my first two questions. The others are important, too.

Comment: @BillYan, do you have some long running business logic code running from your widgets code? or maybe you reimplemented some events handlers in your widgets with long running business logic, like paint event?

Comment: @N1ghtLight thank you very much for the direction. you saved my day. I found an recursive paintevent in our code (not written by me). Removing that seems to solve the problem. I owe you an Italian pizza! (I'm serious, If you happen to be in silicon valley?)

Comment: @BillYan, still wasn't there, but one day... :D I will add this as my answer to you question then =P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such behavior very likely can occur when UI event loop is overloaded with events or some business logic takes too long time. You should to check your business logic and move it to separate thread or run asynchronous.

Comment: one more question for you, why doesn't mac's framework queue the events (signal source) when the thread is busy? they just discard them? and there is no return error when this happens, that sucks.

Comment: unprocessed events queue should has some maximum size, if the queue is full then new events not added to it at all. some background - https://qt-project.org/wiki/ThreadsEventsQObjects#47bf77cab852bf395a980b572877aa84